# What to return when a NSURL results in nil

Tags: swift, null, static-methods

I have a static function which just reads a security scoped bookmark from NSUserdefaults. Like this:

```
static func desktopURL()->NSURL {
    let desktopData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("desktopSecurityBookmark")
    if (desktopData != nil){
        let desktop = try! NSURL(byResolvingBookmarkData: desktopData!, options: NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions.WithSecurityScope, relativeToURL: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: nil)
        desktop.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        return desktop
    } else {
        // what the heck to return when URL was not set in the first place??
        let desktopNil = NSURL() // :D ??? I need to return at leas something or not? 
        return desktopNil
    }
}
```

I mean I need to return at least something or not?

Comment: You should either create or follow specific design in regards to returned value of any function. Now, I don't have any idea of what your `desktopURL` is, therefore anything you want to return is acceptable since you are creating your own API in this case.

Comment: @user57213 A swifty way of doing things can also include throwing an exception.

Comment: how would you go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with these situations is to make your return type optional, then you can return nil if your desktopData is nil. It is usually easier to handle the logic for a nil response in the function calling this function

Eg

```
static func desktopURL() -> NSURL? {
    if let desktopData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("desktopSecurityBookmark")
    {
        let desktop = try! NSURL(byResolvingBookmarkData: desktopData!, options: NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions.WithSecurityScope, relativeToURL: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: nil)
        desktop.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        return desktop
    } else {
        return nil 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! good point! Did not thought of that. pretty straight forward. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all :) glad I could help. Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer? I get rep points for it :P